# Radiant CMS page saving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

In Radiant CMS when I'm trying to save any page that has any PageType but "normal" (Archive, Index,etc.) I get this error:

NoMethodError in Admin/pagesController#update

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

With clean Radiant everything's work, my radiant carried with some extension, which may cause problem. Can anyone give me any clue how can I solve this problem? Thanks.

ps. I apologize for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was with the extension loading order. 
reordering extension list  "config.extension" in envrionment.rb solved this .